# What does C in LC_ALL=C mean?

Tags: environment-variables, locale

I know very well that to override locale settings we can use `LC_ALL` prepended to the command one wants to run. I also know `C` uses default locale of a system. But what does `C` stand for ?

Comment: Relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Comment: @andrew.46 Make it an answer. If you can find a link to Slackware documentation - that's even better, and I'll accept

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/219945/why-lang-c-not-d-or-e-or-f

Comment: @Melebius Of course, Gilles as always has the right answer. Good find, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only *solid* hint I could was from some Slackware documentation written by the great Patrick Volkerding. In the file `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh` he has made the following comment:

```
# 'C' is the old Slackware (and UNIX) default, which is 127-bit ASCII
# with a charmap setting of ANSI_X3.4-1968.  These days, it's better to
# use en_US.UTF-8 or another modern $LANG setting (or at least en_US)
# to support extended character sets.
#export LANG=C
```

Without giving away what the 'C' actually stands for, but I would *guess* that 'C' is an alias for this very lowest and safest level of locale.... Not very satisfactory I know :(.

To see this comment for yourself in the Slackware package try the following:

```
wget http://slackware.osuosl.org/slackware-14.2/source/a/etc/_etc.tar.gz
tar -zxvf _etc.tar.gz etc/profile.d/lang.sh.new --strip-components 2
```

And then open the file `lang.sh.new` with your favoured text editor...

Answer (score 17):

`C` stands for the C programming language.  It is a synonym for the `POSIX` locale.

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_02

> The POSIX locale can be specified by assigning to the appropriate environment variables the values "C" or "POSIX".

Comment: OK , so . . . .what part of that link am I supposed to read ? Edit your post please  to actually cite that link properly

Comment: Same thinking, but may be due to the 1st implementation of `gettext` was in C language. Also not for "default locale of a system" but actually "default locale of each application".  The developer can use different original/source locale than `en_US` or `en`. It could be Arabic, Chinese, French, German, Japanese... it doesn't matter.